# How to generate random numbers from log-normal distribution with a given mean and SD in SAS?

Tags: function, macros, sas, distribution, random

Wenping (Wendy) Zhang [points out](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/198-31.pdf)
that the SAS `RAND` [function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/p0fpeei0opypg8n1b06qe4r040lv.htm) "basically gives "standard" distribution".

The author describes an interesting SAS `%rndnmb` macro to generate data from “non-standard” distributions. Unfortunately the code in unavailable. So, I dared to do it by myself.

If I understand correctly the Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) that *y* is from the log-normal distribution if
*y = exp^(mu + sigma * Z)*.
The following formulas connect the *mean* and *variance* of the non-logarithmized sample values:
*mu = ln((mean^2)/(sqrt(variance + mean^2))*
and
*sigma = sqrt(ln(1 + (variance)/(mean^2)))*.

If that correct, my *y* will be drawn from log-normal distribution when
Z is from standard normal distribution Z with mu' = 0, sigma' = 1.

Finally, is it correct that *y* is from lognormal distribution with *mean* and *variance* if
*y = exp^(ln((mean^2)/(sqrt(variance + mean^2)) + sqrt(ln(1 + (variance)/(mean^2))) * Z)*
?

My SAS code is:
`/*I use StdDev^2 notation instead of variance here. */`
`DATA nonStLogNorm;`
`nonStLN = exp(1)**(log((mean**2)/(sqrt(StdDev^2 + mean**2)) +
sqrt(log(1 + (StdDev^2)/(mean**2))) * rand('UNIFORM'));`
`RUN;`

References:
`RAND` function by Rick Wicklin:
http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/07/10/stop-using-ranuni/
http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/08/24/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-sas/

Comment: The problem is that I get a data set (1000 variates with values between 79.5200 and 79.7120) with the mean (79.6137057) close to `mean` (81.2243980) but the SD (15.6962440) is very distinct (much lower) from `StdDev` (0.05536378). Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the inverse cumulative distribution function. This is the function that is the inverse of the normalized integral of the distribution over the entire domain. So at 0% is your most negative possible value and 100% is your most positive. Practically though you would calmp to something like 0.01% and 99.99% or something like that as otherwise you'll end up at infinite for a lot of distributions.

Then from there you only need to random a number in a range (0,1) and plug that into the function. Remember to clamp it!

```
double CDF = 0.5 + 0.5*erf((ln(x) - center)/(sqrt(2)*sigma))
```

so

```
double x = exp(inverf((CDF - 0.5)*2.0)*sqrt(2)*sigma + center);
```

should give you the requested distribution. inverf is the inverse of the erf function. It is a common function but not in math.h typically.

Did a SIMD based random number generator that needed to do distributions. This worked fine, the above will work assuming I didn't flub up something while typing.

As requested how to clamp:

```
   //This is how I do it with my Random class where the first argument
   //is the min value and the second is the max 
   double CDF = Random::Range(0.0001,0.9999); //Depends on what you are using to random

   //How you get there from Random Ints
   unsigned int RandomNumber = rand();
    //Conver number to range [0,1]
   double CDF = (double)RandomNumber/(double)RAND_MAX; 
   //now clamp it to a min, max of your choosing
   CDF = CDF*(max - min) + min;
```

Comment: thank you, but what exactly should I do by clamping ? Could you please put the code? By the 'exp' you mean 'CONSTANT('E')**'?

Comment: There you go, edited in how to clamp the value. Remember the quality of your random number generator significantly effects the quality of your distribution. I'm not familiar with SAS so I gave you some C code equivalent. But yes the exp() function is the constant 'e' to  some power. There may be an easier way to do this in your enviroment but behind the scene this is what is being done.

Comment: Nope comment above stated a way of doing it from any random number generator. Unsure of what SAS even is. So I gave him the C-equivalent and the math to create his own in a given programming language. Was only hoping it could help him figure it out and mention this in the comment above yours.

Comment: I' didn't see the full comment. I submitted the code (CONSTANT('E')**(inverf(((0.5+0.5*erf((log(Min+FLOOR((1+Max-Min)*RAND('LOGNORMAL'))-81.2243980)/(sqrt(2)*15.6962440)))-      0.5)*2.0)*sqrt(2)*15.6962440 + 81.2243980));) but unfortunately SAS doesn't know inverf()...

Comment: Could you please explain what is "double" means in the case of CDF and X ? As I understand x = exp(inverf((CDF - 0.5)*2.0)*sqrt(2)*sigma + center), where CDF=(0.5 + 0.5*erf((ln(x) - center)/(sqrt(2)*sigma))). Right?

Comment: double is a 64-bit floating point number in c-style syntax. 

Here are where I got the equations, plus a bit of napkin math to do the inversion of the CDF.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

 
Here is a C-style white paper for approximating the inverse of erf to around 1E-6 or so. http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/gems_erfinv.pdf

Also so you know the RAND needs to have no bias. It should be uniformly distributed over a linear domain. Equal chance for every number. Apologies I don't know anything about SAS or I'd help with that syntax.

Comment: user2927848: Thanks for the explanation :). I found: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/07/22/the-inverse-cdf-method/

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Z` to be drawn from the standard normal distribution, shouldn't you obtain it by calling `RAND('NORMAL')` rather than `RAND('UNIFORM')`?

Comment: What is "it"? Does `RAND('UNIFORM')` return a bell-shaped histogram?

Comment: I meant the following code (after changing the RAND ('UNIFORM) to RAND('NORMAL')) gave me the bell-shaped distribution: DATA gfgrgdgd; do nefff = 1 to 1000; nonStLN = CONSTANT('E')**LOG((81.2243980**2)/(sqrt(15.6962440**2+81.2243980**2)) +sqrt(LOG(1+(15.6962440**2)/(81.2243980**2)))*RAND('NORMAL')));output;end;run; proc univariate data = gfgrgdgd; histogram nonStLN;run;

Comment: sqrt(LOG(1+(15.6962440**2)/(81.2243980**2))) is about 0.1915, and as you can see from the graph of log-normal with parameter sigma=0.25 (on the Wikipedia page), the resulting distribution looks bell-shaped. It's actually skewed, of course, but the skewness is hard to see by eye (unlike the skewness for sigma=1, which is quite obvious). If you're still getting a tiny standard deviation of `nonStLN`, however, I'm puzzled.

Comment: Now my problem is inerf() - SAS doesn'n know it. It is said that quantile() is "the inverse of the CDF function" what user2927848 mentioned in his answer.